# Putting Italics into an xtable caption

Tags: r, r-markdown, xtable

I am working on a project in R-markdown. I have been trying to get the 'n' to italicize but I keep getting error messages. Listed below is my latest attempt.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results="asis"} 
print(xtable(describe(PDS_Admin[3:15]), align="lccccccccccccc", 
             caption=paste("Descriptive Statistics for PDS Administrators", italic(n), "= 13")), 
             type="latex", caption.placement= "top", comment=F, latex.environments ="flushleft") 
```
````

I know this seems like a mundane detail. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LaTeX tags, such as `\textit{}` for italics, directly inside the caption:

````
```{r, results="asis"}
## Note the \\ that escapes the '\' character
xtable(mtcars[1:13,], align="lccccccccccc", type="latex",
  caption="Built-in mtcars dataset for \\textit{n} = 13")
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It was driving me nuts.